# Short way of creating bunch of php/html files?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a website.The website will have so many gifs/pics and so I have to create php/html file just for showing a gif/pic.So I just have to create so many php/html file or there is any short way.

For ex. I create gif.html and gif1.html , gif10000.html,takes so many times.Thought maybe there is a short way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an element to display in `GET` parameter, for example:

```
show_picture.php?file=gif10000.gif
```

and in `PHP` retrieve it by `$_GET['file']` (make sure you sanitize the input first).

Here is full PHP:

```
<?php
$allowedImages = array(
    'gif10000.gif',
    'gif2.gif' //etc
);

$file = $_GET['file'];
if (in_array($file, $allowedImages)) { 
    echo '<img src="'.$file.'" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually i am absolute beginner in php,so this solution is hard for me.Thanks anyway...

Comment: This *is* the easy way to do it, though.  Read up on using URL parameters, and do that, instead of trying to generate hundreds of nearly identical PHP files.

Comment: Sorry but i have to ask.I will include that php code above and when i click gif/pic , it will be opened as gif2.php/html ?  @WillBriggs

Comment: What PHP does is basically just displays and image provided in GET param.

Comment: No, Erman, it's like divix has at the top of his answer: `show_picture.php?file=gif10000.gif`.